# Iterating through mysql table to fill array in Node

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have a table `swipe` that I need to iterate through to fill an array that I can use to display a `matches list` to the user. The structure is the following (a valid match between two users):

[image]

Here is my raw logic to iterate through the table and get `match objects` that I will push into an array:

```
user = current_user_id;

for (swipes in swipe)
{
  if (id_user === user)
  {
    to_match === id_user_matched;
    for (swipes in swipe)
    {
        if (id_user === to_match && id_user_matched === user)
        {
            matches_list[].push({“id_match”: id_match, “id_user_matched”: to_match});
        }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do this in my backend with either an `sql query` or Node code?

Thank you!

Comment: If I have understood well, you can create the mysql query in order to retrieve just to rows concerning to id_user you want. After that you can populate the array with the query result.

Comment: @Wolfetto do you think it's possible in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about node, but the SQL you want to run will look something like this:

```
select s2.id_match, s1.id_user_matched
from swipe s1
inner join swipe s2 ON s2.id_user = s1.id_user_matched and s2.id_user_matched = @user
where s1.id_user = @user
```

Comment: It work by joining the table to itself. This replaces the loops in the sample code from the question... run the query, and the results go directly into the `matches_list` array. But again, I've never used node, so figuring out how to run the query is up to you.

Comment: Amazing! What do `s1` and `s2` mean?

Comment: Table aliases, so you can distinguish the two instances of the table from each other.

Comment: Thank you Joel! It works like a charm, SQL seems to be very powerful, is my query realistic in a production environment?

Comment: Yes, this is realistic